# Form works in IE and Chrome but not Firefox

Tags: forms

I'm not sure whats happened to my form, but suddenly it no longer works in Firefox but works fine in IE and Chrome.

When anything is entered into any of the form fields, you cant make the text out in Firefox.  But it looks fine in IE and Chrome.

My Form https://californiaschooloflaw.com/index.php?page=admissions-evaluation

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Firefox cant handle the form text boxes as small as the other browsers can. Once I increased the height all is well.